# Exclude a specific node for a specific input in consistent hashing?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, consistent-hashing

If my input key hashes to anywhere between `machine1` and `machine2` in the circle, and our algorithm goes clockwise, then we know `machine2` will be returned.

```
consistentHash.getMachine(myInput) = machine2;
```

What if I want to avoid `machine2` for `myInput`? Say, `myInput` is an account ID and it has maximized its budget on `machine2`. Is there a way to specify that extra info and get back `machine0` instead, i.e.

```
consistentHash.getMachine(input, excludes=[machine2]) = machine0;
```

I'm interested in both an algorithmic explanation and any existing implementations/libraries (Java preferred), if they exist.

[image: Text]

(Image source: http://michaelnielsen.org/blog/consistent-hashing)

Comment: Fyi, your link gives a 404

Comment: Thanks! Apparently SO decided the link should include the `_` I put at its end for italic ...